# Interesting math problem

Tags: algebra-precalculus, word-problem

In a far-away country, every shop is owned by one of three companies. One day, a new law was instituted to
fight the monopoly. If at the end of any given day one of the companies owns more than half of all the shops
and the number of shops it owns is divisible by 5, then the company must close all but 1/5 of its shops. Is it possible that three days after the law takes into effect the number of shops owned by each company decreased?

Comment: Is there a tag for communism?

Comment: The assumption is that in the period of these 3 days no new Shops open and the only closing of shops is due to the new law?

Comment: Lmao, this problem is actually from the moscow math olympiad and I'm working through them for practice but they don't really keep the answers anywhere.

Comment: @maxmilgram yes I think so. do you have any insight?

Comment: Please try to make the titles of your questions more informative. For example, *Why does $a<b$ imply $a+c<b+c$?* is much more useful for other users than *A question about inequality.* From [How can I ask a good question?](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/a/589/): *Make your title as descriptive as possible. In many cases one can actually phrase the title as the question, at least in such a way so as to be comprehensible to an expert reader.* You can find more tips for choosing a good title [here](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/a/10144/).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assume that the companies are called $A$, $B$ and $C$ and they have initially $a$, $b$ and $c$, respectively. Assume also that they close in that order: $A$ first, then $B$ and finally $C$ (since a permutation of a solution is also a solution).

To start, forget about the condition that shops close only if their number is a multiple of $5$. In the mathematical world, you can have fractions of shops! And if you have a rational solution of the problem, you can obtain a solution that satisfies all the conditions of the problem by multiplication by the right constant.

Now, let's see what happening:

1. $A$'s shops close first: this means that $a>b+c$. Because of the new law, company $A$ has to keep only $a/5$ shops. The $b$ and $c$ shops of companies $B$ and $C$ are unaffected.
2. $B$'s shops close: this means that $b>\frac{a}{5}+c$. Because of the new law, company $B$ has to keep only $b/5$ shops. The $a/5$ and $c$ shops of companies $A$ and $C$ are unaffected.
3. $C$'s shops close: this means that $c>\frac{a}{5}+\frac{b}{5}$. Because of the new law, company $C$ has to keep only $c/5$ shops. The $a/5$ and $b/5$ shops of companies $A$ and $B$ are unaffected.

Therefore, $(a,b,c)$ should satisfy a system of linear inequalities

$$a>0, b>0, c>0, a-b-c>0, a-5b+5c<0, a+b-5c<0$$

You can find a solution by trial and error. For example, after reordering, the solutions by @vujazzman and @Hans work.

You can also visualize the solution set in space: since each inequality represents an open half-space, the solution set is the interior of a (possibly empty, possibly unbounded) polyhedron. Note that, if non-empty, it cannot be bounded since a multiple of a solution is also a solution.

---

It is not that hard to find solutions by hand. Write $c=5k$, $b=5(k+q)$ and $a=5(k+q+r)$, where $k$, $q$ and $r$ are positive integers.

The linear equations are equivalent to

$$
r>k, q+r<4k, 2q+r<3k
$$

We can check for small values of $k$. For $k=1$, there is no solution. But there is one with $k=2$: $q=1$ and $r=3$. This gives $c=10$, $b=15$ and $a=30$.

Answer (score 0):

Its possible. Take, for instance the number of owned shops at the outset to be 45, 75, 125. Then after day 1, the owned shops number 25, 45, 75. After day 2, they number 15, 25, 45, and after day 3, they number 9, 15, 25.

Answer (score 0):

The set $\{325, 170, 100\}$ works.